# add mxgetfield to mexinterface from gfortran

Tags: c, matlab, fortran

I am new to programming in Fortran and C, and have some experience in Matlab `.m` files.

I am trying to call Fortran subroutine from Matlab for which I am building a mexfunction. In that it seems that I have to use `mx_` functions from Matlab for the conversion of data previous to call Fortran subroutines.

The problem I have is that compiling with `gfortran` the functions I have available are the ones `bind`-ed in `mexinterface` downloaded with the compiler. I need to use `mxgetfield` which is not included in `mexinterface`, I tried adding this piece of code to `mexinterface`:

```
function mxgetfield(pm,ind,s) bind(c,name = ‘MXGETFIELD’)
  import c_int, c_ptr, c_char
  integer(c_int) :: pm, ind
  character(c_char) s(*)
  type(c_ptr) :: mxgetfield
end function mxgetfield
```

The compiler compiles it with no problems but when calling the created `.mexw32` with an struct as input Matlab shuts down. The line in my mexfunction which is giving me problems is:

```
call c_f_pointer(mxgetfield(prhs(1),1,”Field1”), Field1_pr, [9])
```

Can anyone tell me how to make mxgetfield available for me?

Answer (score 1):

The first two arguments of mxGetField in your interface block require the VALUE attribute.  The first argument is a pointer, best represented using C_PTR, rather than just an integer.  If you do use an integer, then an integer of C_INTPTR_T is better.  The second argument is probably better represented as being of kind C_SIZE_T.

Comment: Thanks @IanH made this and simplified the code and get something like this in my gateway: 'subroutine mexfunction(nlhs, plhs, nrhs, prhs)' use mysubrout_mod implicit none integer :: nlhs, nrhs, plhs(nlhs), prhs(nrhs) double precision, pointer :: out_ptr, inp_ptr call c_f_pointer(mxgetfield(prhs(1),1,'field1'), inp_ptr,[1]) plhs(1) = mxcreatedoublematrix(1,1,0) call c_f_pointer(mxgetpr(plhs(1)), out_ptr,[1]) call mexprintf('Fortran pointers created'//char(0)) call mysubrout(inp_ptr,out_ptr) end subroutine mexfunction' In 'mysubrout_mod' I am using mexinterface but it is still **not working**...